# Conditional js firing for popup ecommerce tracking in GA

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, popup

So I am working for a hotel company, http://www.kahalaresort.com/ who currently has a popup appear briefly on the homepage promoting an offer.

When the user clicks the offer they are brought to the packages page where they can select an offer and book through the booking engine.

This process has 3 steps:

1. the initial interaction
2. the package selection
3. then the actual booking.

What I am looking to do is associate ecommerce tracking in `GA` (from the booking engine) to clicks on the popup window from the home page while retaining the referring source.

Any initial steps would be super helpful.